# How to completely cover Xbox UWP 'current app' tile on homescreen?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

Defining a splashscreen for a Xbox universal application leads to the following result:

[image: homescreen 'current app' tile]

The source of the image is a `1240x600` `*.jpg` which has a yellow border to indicate the edges of the image. The user who is currently logged in on the Xbox has red as his main color, leading to the red background behind the splashscreen.

I expected the splashscreen image to completely fill the 'current app' tile on the homescreen and not having this additional red background.
Is the latter the intended behaviour or is there a different image I can supply to completely cover this section on the homescreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background is mandatary. A difference path you can take is define a background color of your tile, and use image with transparent color (png) as it will provide better UI.

Comment: Wow, you're right. Did not think, that the tile background color would influence the area where the splash screen is shown. Unfortunately the splash screen itself in my case has a gradient and does not end with the same color on all borders. Why is this handled in this unintuitive way? I mean, the image size of the splash screen already fits nearly perfect and if the app is suspended, the current state of the app is also shown without the border ...